# How to include .js libraries in webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I'm trying to include this js library but is not working. All the code is being compiled without errors.Here the problem is that test.js uses some of the infinitescroll.js library but it seems the aren't in the same scope, so finally i get the error "infinitescroll is not a function" when I open the page in the browser.

What I'm missing here ?

```
window._ = require('lodash');

var $ = window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');


require('script-loader!./jquery.infinitescroll.js');


// Uncaught TypeError: $(...).infinitescroll is not a function
require('./test.js');
```

Comment: Your path `'script-loader!./jquery.infinitescroll.js'` seems wrong. Check it out.

Comment: The path is ok. the library is being compiled but I'm getting the error in the browser.

Comment: Can you show the code of `test.js`?